# How to upload multiple files to a folder in xquery?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How can I upload multiple files to a folder in xquery ?

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more.  Where are the files coming from?  What mechanism are you using to load them into MarkLogic? HTTP, XCC, QConsole?

Comment: I want to upload with a file upload control. User should have the option of uploading multiple or single file. And the file should get saved in Marklogic Server.

Comment: I think he's asking for the MarkLogic XQuery equivalent of the Java server code for file upload, like http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/ paired with, say, browser html/js for form input type="file" .  Iirc, there's lots of browser/client-side trickery sometimes as well the need for the server-side code to propertly handle the http headers - ideally you'd be able to receive a stream for a file upload, rather than read the entire upload contents into memory.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to iterate through a directory on the filesystem and insert those files at some location in the db, like this?

```
for $e in xdmp:filesystem-directory('c:\my-files\')/dir:entry
let $file := xdmp:filesystem-file($e/dir:pathname)
let $dest-uri := concat('/dest-path/',$e/dir:filename)
where ($e/dir:type eq 'file')
return xdmp:document-insert($dest-uri,$file)
```

Comment: Question is unclear, but it does seem he's trying to upload from a client, not a server.

Comment: what will be dir namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Information Studio](http://community.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/books/info_studio.pdf). It provides a UI for loading and transforming content. One of the built-in “collectors” allows you to point at a file system directory and recursively load its contents. Information Studio automatically handles the directory traversal and breaking the load up into multiple transactions, among many other conveniences.